# need help Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve displaying a field in my database.

basically at the moment i have

```
'SELECT
 historylist.artist,
 historylist.ID,
 artistlist.lyrics,
 artistlist.ID
FROM historylist
 INNER JOIN artistlist
  ON historylist.ID = artistlist.ID
 ORDER BY historylist.date_played DESC
LIMIT 1;'
```

Now  this is not correct.  I need to use the history list ID to link the artistlist ID.  Then grab the field artistlist.lyrics. then display it.   Right now when i do it like that  it  shows the lyrics field but its null.  So i am guessing its  searching historylist table

```
  CREATE TABLE `historylist` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `songID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `date_played` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `duration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `artist` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `album` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `albumyear` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `buycd` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `picture` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `listeners` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `label` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `pline` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `trackno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `composer` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `ISRC` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `catalog` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `UPC` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `feeagency` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
   KEY `date_played` (`date_played`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

that code above is the historylist table

this one is the

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artistlist` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `diskID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NNNNNNNNNN',
  `songtype` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '50',
  `balance` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_played` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_artist_played` datetime DEFAULT '2002-01-01 00:00:01',
  `date_album_played` datetime DEFAULT '2002-01-01 00:00:01',
  `date_title_played` datetime DEFAULT '2002-01-01 00:00:01',
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `artist` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `album` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `pline` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `trackno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `composer` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ISRC` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `catalog` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `UPC` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `feeagency` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `albumyear` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `genre` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `buycd` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `info` text,
   `lyrics` text,
   `picture` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `count_played` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `count_requested` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
     UNIQUE KEY `filename` (`filename`),
      KEY `date_played` (`date_played`),
     KEY `date_artist_played` (`date_artist_played`),
    KEY `date_album_played` (`date_album_played`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=347 ;
```

Now basically on every song  i can show the data making the call to history list.  but i need  to  use the historylist id its pulling.  to then connect to the artistlist id  so it pulls the lyrics field

hope that helps more

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "i am guessing its searching historylist table" but your join looks good. Are you sure there is a historylist.ID which is also in artistlist.ID?

Comment: Can you post your both table structures?

Comment: i need it to show just 1 result. to show the lyrics of the current artist being shown.

Comment: This doesn't look correct `ON historylist.ID = artistlist.ID`, unless the tables have 1-1 relationship. It should probably be `ON historylist.ID = artistlist.historylistID` or `ON historylist.artistlistID = artistlist.ID`

Comment: then you need to put the current artist in where condition

Comment: Post the tables' structure and a few rows from each.

Comment: one table is  history which is showing the current artist.

Comment: the other links to the actual data  sorry pressed enter.   but basically its a now playing script  so it shows the current song  being played. i  can  get it to show the album artist  song.  but the lyrics  is in a different table  called songlist

Comment: WHERE songlist.lyrics = '?'  what would the expression be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your join condition is incorrect.

```
ON historylist.ID = artistlist.ID
```

If this to be work both table have to have 1-1 relationship. Looking at your table structure i think correct condition would be

```
ON historylist.artist = artistlist.artist
```

Comment: There has to be a relationship between these two tables and you have to use that linking column for join, other wise join won't work.

Comment: well they are related the artistlist stores all the data for the songs in the database.  the historylist  shows what the latest played.

Comment: what about filename ?  thats in both tables

Comment: yeah that did it  just joined them by historylist.filename = artistfilename   and now it shows :)  thanks for leading me to the answer